# NSURL & NSData causing delay on view loading

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsurl, nsjsonserialization

I am using NSURL and NSData to download information from my JSON file then place it into my table view in my application. Information includes some text and images for the users. This all works fine apart from the fact the view takes about 15 seconds to load and appears to be frozen before appearing. I have tried everything to try fix this including a solution mentioned to use a NSURL Session but I can't seem to get anything to work correctly for me. I have posted the important parts of the code below.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     [self.tableViewObject setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRefresh:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableViewObject addSubview:refreshControl];
    self.tableViewObject.estimatedRowHeight = 70.0;
    self.tableViewObject.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(didHide) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                   initWithTarget:self
                                   action:@selector(dismissKeyboard)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    [self downloadmessages];
   timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(downloadmessages)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{
        return [trackin count];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { return UITableViewAutomaticDimension; }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ChatCellTest";
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier2 = @"ChatCellTest2";

    if([[trackin[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"senderID"] isEqual: @"me"]){
        ChatCellTest *cell = (ChatCellTest *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)

        {

            NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatCellTest" owner:self options:nil];

            cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

        }


        cell.background.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        cell.background.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        cell.message.text = [trackin[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"message"];
         cell.time.text = [trackin[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"time"];

        cell.avatar.image =  [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:mypic]]];
         cell.avatar.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.avatar.frame.size.height /2;
         cell.avatar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        return cell;
    }
    else{
        ChatCellTest *cell = (ChatCellTest *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier2];

        if (cell == nil)
        {

            NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatCellTest2" owner:self options:nil];

            cell = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];

        }


        cell.background.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
        cell.background.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
       cell.message.text = [reversedArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"message"];
        cell.time.text = [reversedArray[indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"time"];

        cell.avatar.image =  [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc]initWithString:otherpic]]];
        cell.avatar.layer.cornerRadius =  cell.avatar.frame.size.height /2;
        cell.avatar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        return cell;

    }

}



-(void)downloadmessages
{

    NSURL *blogURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://tutific.udropoff.com/api/getmessages.php?conID=%@", subjects2]];
    NSLog(@"URL = %@", blogURL);

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:blogURL];

    if(jsonData == nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"Please check your internet connection and try again." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        return;
    }
    else{
        NSError *error = nil;
        dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
        NSMutableArray *temp = [[dict objectForKey:@"tutific"]mutableCopy];
        trackin = [temp copy];
        NSUInteger *elements = [trackin count];
        NSLog(@"Number of Shows : %d", elements);

        if (elements == 0)
        {
            //[udropofftrack removeAllObjects];
            trackin=nil;
            [_tableViewObject reloadData];
            // self.noorder.hidden=FALSE;

        }


        else{

            NSString *success = [trackin[0] valueForKey:@"type"];
            if ([success  isEqual: @"error"])
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection Error" message:@"Your application failed to connect to uDropOff servers. Please update your application in the App Store." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                return;

            }

        }
    }
    [_tableViewObject reloadData];
}


@end
```

Comment: Never perform network access on the main thread. Please see Apple's [LazyTableImages](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394) sample app.

Comment: What you have suggested is not the same as my issue, that is just for images. I have the same issue if I have a view without images loading from my JSON, it does not load as slow but still loads slow. The issues pointed out in that post only are pointing towards the images being loaded.

Comment: You have two instances of the same basic issue - you are downloading data from the Internet on the main thread. Never do that. The duplicate covers the specifics of the images in the table. There are countless other examples that demonstrate how to properly download and process JSON data. Please do a little searching on the subject.

Comment: Sorry about that, I had looked online and tried out solutions and could not get them working thats why I posted the code here to see if anyone had some easier solutions. I will try using dispatch_async as someone pointed out in the thread you sent to me, do you think that will work??

Comment: Yes, `dispatch_async` using a background queue is correct.